# Userform resilient to Unload call

Tags: excel, vba

I am having a weird issue trying to `Unload` Useforms before showing another one.
My worksheet is made of a master `UserForm`, called `UFMainMenu`, which can call others. When the master one call an userform, it hides using something like this in the master UserForm code:

```
Private Sub BtnSupprimerValeur_Click()
    Me.Hide
    UFSupInstanceParametre.Show
End Sub
```

This works as intended, and opens `UFSupInstanceParametre`
Inside `UFSupInstanceParametre`, if user closes it, the code `Unload` `UFSupInstanceParametre` and launches back my master `UserForm`:

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
        Unload Me
        Call mainMenu
    End If
End Sub
```

mainMenu is this simple sub :

```
Sub mainMenu()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    Dim objLoop As Object
    'The following loop is just for me to see if previous userform was indeed unloaded, and if not it unloads it again
    For Each objLoop In VBA.UserForms
        If objLoop.Name <> "UFMainMenu" Then
            Unload objLoop
        End If
    Next objLoop
    
    UFMainMenu.Show
    
End Sub
```

The problems are :
-The `Unload Me` inside `UFSupInstanceParametre` doesn't indeed Unload `UFSupInstanceParametre`, since it still appears on screen.
-Inside the `For` Loop in mainMenu, when ran steps by steps I see that `UFSupInstanceParametre` hasn't been unloaded, and I confirm that the code then runs the line `Unload objLoop`, which should unload it anyway. It doesn't, `UFSupInstanceParametre` is still on screen. To be 100% sure that it isn't unloaded, I tried running a second time the `For` Loop, which found again `UFSupInstanceParametre` as still loaded, and again tried to Unload it with the line `Unload objLoop`, without success.
-Code throws no error, it just won't unload any userform.
-Code launches the master Userform as intended after trying to unload others in mainMenu, but with the other one still visible behind.

I have to admit that I'm kinda lost on this one, I know that there is just one simple property about UserForms that I am missing, but no way for me to find it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you really need to unload a form? Do you understand the consequences (destroying the object, issues with default instances that are immediately recreated...) ? Try just to set the form to hidden (`Me.Hide` or `objLoop.Hide`). And read https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/

Comment: I need it to be unloaded yes, because they need to be re-initialized with updated data and condition, so just hiding it and showing it again would make it appears back to its previous state, and I can't go that way.  I could use Hide and Show, and reset the userform to its original state when unhidden, but in my case it would be way more efficient to just unload it and start from scratch

Comment: I have to add that each userform launched from the master one isn't intended to be launched again and again, but only in some cases the user might want to re-do the operation. I don't have a lot of interest in keeping them into memory

Comment: `Unload Me` is always a horrible idea - you destroy an object while its code is still running. Are you sure that you always see the same instance - I would assume that you see the newly created default instance every time. Anyhow, why not moving the code that fills the form to a sub and call it from `Activate` instead of `Initialize`.event? Not talking about a MVC-System where the data is controlled by the Controler rather than the View

Comment: I'll try, but about the Unload Me, I added those after seeing that the `For` Loop failed to unload each UF, to check if it would work. I'm gonna go with the `Activate` event even if it means adding more code than I expected, since it has to make the UF clear some stuff from its interface. Still, I feel a little like dodging the problem doing that, I don't really understand why it just won't unload them.

Comment: @FunThomas Using Me.Hide on the userform and calling it again later makes it brain dead. It showes up in the same state as when it was cancelled but doesn't react to buttons click etc

Comment: Ok so to add another level of "Whatever the hell is excel doing", I found out something : The 2 userforms hiding out each other when one calls the other one fails. It throws error saying that it can't show a userform already visible (even if it is actually hidden). However, if I show my userforms as vbmodeless everything works perfectly. No idea why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot explain in detail every behavior of your code, but the main problem comes from the fact that you interrupt the code of your child form in `UserForm_QueryClose` by showing the main form. VBA is single threaded and in the moment you show a form modal, the code of a routine is interrupted, the form is displayed and the code behind (eg Activate-Trigger) is executed.

Once your main form is hidden again, the interrupted `QueryClose`-code of the child form is continued. What you need to know it that the queryClose-Trigger is called whenever the form it about to be destroyed - this might be case if user pressed the system close button (the red "X"-button) or if somewhere in your code an `unload` statement is executed. (unless you set the parameter `Cancel = True`).

Now what happens if you issue an `Unload`-statement within the `queryClose`-Trigger? I don't know exactly, but it seems the runtime knows that you are already in the middle of an `Unload`-process and ignores the next attempts - this explains why you never get rid of the instance in your `mainmenu`-code.

The fact that showing the form `vbmodeless` results in a complete different behaviour is easy to explain: The code displaying the form (still talking about your `queryClose`-routine) continues to run as showing a form non-modal doesn't interrupt the code.

So how to solve that mess:

What you need to implement is a kind of controller instance that show/hides the forms. Don't let the forms be "clever", it's not their job to destroy themselves or to know which form to show next - that's the job of the controller. And the job of the controller would also be to decide if or if not to destroy any form object.

A quick solution could be to let the main form be the controller. This is for sure not best practice, but it would be easy to implement.
In the main form, you put the code to show the child form like this (triggered from a button or any other event)

```
Sub showChildform()
    Me.Hide
    UFMainMenu.Show
    Me.Show
End Sub
```

That's all.

In `UFMainMenu`, you can remove the complete code of `UserForm_QueryClose`. The only thing you need to have in mind now it how your child form can be closed. If you have only the system close button, you don't have to do anything - just keep in mind that pressing the button will destroy the form. But if you add a button like Cancel, Close, OK or whatever, you need to "leave" the form per code. Options are `Unload` or `Hide`. `Unload` is, as already mentioned, very bad practice, use the statement `Me.Hide` in the trigger code of the button.

But that leaves you in the situation that the form can be left with two different states: Hidden or Destroyed. If you want to be consistent, put the following code into the `UserForm_QueryClose`-Trigger, it will hide the form but cancel the destroying when the system close button is pressed. For this, it checks the parameter `CloseMode`: If it has the value `vbFormControlMenu`, the user pressed close (there are [other cases](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/queryclose-event) where the trigger is called)

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
        Cancel = True
        Me.Hide
    End If
End Sub
```

Now, why is it considered bad practice that a form destroys itself? Short answer: That's not the task of a form (or any other object). It would invalidate a reference and the calling code wouldn't know. The calling code cannot check anything that was done on the form, if the form was left pressing an OK- or Cancel-Button. I could explain this in more detail, but the mentioned Rubberduck article explains it already very well.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanations, It kinda makes sense now. Too bad VBA is only single threaded, I guess since it's an old language that maybe wasn't useful at the time they designed it.